# How do I check if cell contents match a specific string?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a quick Excel Macro that iterates through a raw input range, row by row, looking for different text values (which it sends to other worksheets as needed). I'm running into a problem with my If statements.

Code snippet of the affected area

```
For i = 1 To (maxRow - 1)

    If IsEmpty(myRange.Cells(i, 3)) Then

        'Do things

    ElseIf myRange.Cells(i, 3).Value = "Company Meeting" Then

        'Do other things

    End If

Next
```

The code inside the ElseIf never runs. I changed the ElseIf line to

```
ElseIf myRange.Cells(i, 3).Value = 3 Then
```

...and added a 3 to the column we're looking at in the input, and it ran the code inside ElseIf. This tells me that my code is looking at the right columns and the right cells. For some reason, the issue only happens if my ElseIf is looking for a string value - if I try to check for a number I don't see any issues.

I've also tried the following:

```
ElseIf myRange.Cells(i, 3).Text = "Company Meeting" Then
ElseIf myRange.Cells(i, 3) = "Company Meeting" Then
```

...with the same results

How can I check if the text in the cell matches a specific string with an If statement?

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces or other unprintable characters in the data that would cause Excel not to see them as the same, as this method is looking for an EXACT match.

Comment: After your `For i = 1` line, add `Debug.Print myRange.Cells(i, 3)` to see if you are even looking in the right place. Press `Ctrl` + `G` to open up the immediate window. As @ScottCraner stated, you are looking for an exact match. So if your cell's value actually says `Company Meeting on Tuesday`, that is not an exact match.

Comment: I would use `Debug.Print "'" & myRange.Cells(i, 3) & "'"` Which will help find any non printable characters.

Comment: @ScottCraner I thought that too, so I copied directly from my If statement and pasted into an empty cell, but I'm still having problems. I've also tried copying from the cell to the if statement.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax so the error has to be with the data or the location or something on your side that we can't do but guess.

Comment: @ScottCraner Debug.Print helped! Turns out my data source was using some other strange whitespace character. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Scott Craner, I have had issues dealing with whitespace characters within excel. Copy and paste the contents of the cell into notepadd++ and then enable hidden chars with something like:

- View->Show Symbol->Show White Space and TAB

This may help you identify exactly what you are looking at within you cell!